# When adding animation, UITableView stops working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

The animation seems to be superimposed on the table and it stops working! The video shows that with a small animation size the table works correctly, but when you add the size of the animation, the table stops working

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nLm_uwt-AhIrJvib80lLh3ZqBH1b_SWY
https://drive.google.com/open?id=15Cv4JvadTzJnB_MHG9ksCugnZqVcpgCc
Source Project: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eGDZ0Z0Wf_2co2lEV9KOWE4LISC5Vogw

```
import UIKit
import Lottie

class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

let sportMenu = ["Начать тренировку","Выбрать другую","Советы по упражнениям"]


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return sportMenu.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
    cell?.textLabel?.text = sportMenu[indexPath.row]
    return cell!


}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "StartTraining", sender: nil)
    default:
        break
    }
}


@IBOutlet weak var animation: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var settingsIcon: UIBarButtonItem!


let animationView = AnimationView()
let size: CGFloat = 540

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    tableView.isScrollEnabled = false


    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic

    let animation = Animation.named("Espander")
    animationView.animation = animation
    animationView.play()
    animationView.loopMode = .loop

    animationView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size, height: size)
    animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    view.addSubview(animationView)

    animationView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    animationView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: -120).isActive = true
    animationView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size).isActive = true
    animationView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size).isActive = true
    animationView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true


 }
```

Comment: Why don't you try `view.bringSubview(toFront: tableView)` after you add the animationView to the view. It seems that the animation view is getting the taps instead of the tableView. You can also try `animationView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`.

Comment: Thanks bro!!!! animationView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false :)))

Comment: @GustavoConde: Please add your comment as an answer so it can be found easier and accepted by Andrey Velin.

Comment: @wvteijlingen done.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your animationView is absorving the taps, so that's why the tableView doesn't respond.

Just add `animationView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`